# o365 api events won't allow atendees to edit the time/add more users

Tags: api, outlook, o365rwsclient

I'm using the office api to create outlook events. The resulting ones won't allow the atendees to edit the start/end time of the event or to add more people to the event (unlike outlook created events).

Is there a parameter that I'm missing to do that?
I'm currently using these docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents and posting in the format shown there:

```
{
  "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": "2014-02-02T18:00:00-08:00",
  "StartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
  "End": "2014-02-02T19:00:00-08:00",
  "EndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "janets@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Name": "Janet Schorr"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!